# Can Resampling be used for estimation and goodness of fit test?

Tags: data-mining, bootstrap, computational-statistics, resampling

I am trying to compare my data with empirical distributions. But I don't have enough data to cut them to estimation data and validation data. I am trying a resampling approach and would like to see if it's correct :

1. resample the data randomly
2. estimate the parameters of the empirical distribution using a part of the data
3. use goodness of fit test (e.g kolomogorov smirnov) to compare the model with estimated parameters on 100% of the data?
4. redo the same
5. Take the results and see the number of time the model was not rejected if it's more than 60% of the resample iterations then the model is not rejected for this case

Is this a correct way to do this a more general estimation and see if some data follow some empirical distribution ?

If not, is there another way to do this?

At first I was doing parameter estimation on the data and after that doing a goodness of fit test on the data and the model, but this only help in giving a hard no on some models.

Comment: Definitely it makes sense, especially if you use bootstrap. There is an excellent book on this topic, with accompanying R code, from Ewout Steyerberg.

Comment: Could you give me the name of the book ? Thanks

Comment: Clinical Prediction Models: www.springer.com/us/book/9780387772431